# How to keep/change the class after using paste()

Tags: r, netcdf, netcdf4

I am working with netCDF-files and have the following problem:

I created 70 objects of "ncdf4" class. They are named ncin1950 - ncin2019.
In the next step I need to extract certain information (so called "consecutive_dry_days_index_per_time_period") from the single objects which is regulary done by the following command, using ncin1950 as an example:

```
cdd.array1950 <- ncvar_get(ncin1950,"consecutive_dry_days_index_per_time_period")
```

This works perfectly fine.
Since I do not want to apply this command for every single object and thereby 70 times, I tried to use a loop:

```
for (i in 1950:2019) {
  assign(paste0("cdd.array",i), ncvar_get(paste("ncin",i,sep = ""),"consecutive_dry_days_index_per_time_period"))
}
```

This did not work due to this:

```
error in ncvar_get(paste("ncin", i, sep = ""), "consecutive_dry_days_index_per_time_period") : 
  first argument (nc) is not of class ncdf4!
```

I think the reason for this is the fact that paste() automatically creates results of the class "character":

```
> class(paste("ncin",1950,sep = ""))
[1] "character"
```

while

```
> class(ncin1950)
[1] "ncdf4"
```

So the question is, how can I keep the "ncdf4" class in the for-loop while using the paste()-function or anything similar which concatenates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `get()` to use a string to reference an object, `ncvar_get(get(paste("ncin",i,sep = ""))`. Or use `mget()` to get the whole list of objects at once, then `lapply()`.

Or, best of all, rearrange you upstream workflow so that you're creating a *list* of objects, rather than cluttering your workspace with 70 different objects. Then you can operate on the list with a `for` loop, or `lapply`, or fancier methods (e.g. `purrr::map()`). This is more idiomatic and will simplify your life in the long run ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, get() did the job perfectly!

I can see the point with rearranging the workflow with a list of objects. It is definitely a good idea. The thing here is that every single of these 70 objects is already a List of 14, so not sure if it works.